# Retrieve data from the same table if subId is an id of other item

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains some records, and I would like to get only these records that have `subID` to a record with the `id` of the `subID` value. If there is no row with the `id` then do not take this row to the table. Also do not duplicate values if already in the table and do not look at rows that have `subId` 0 because they are as `parents` we can say so they do not have `childs`

```
----------------------------
ID | SUBID | NAME | ENABLED |
30 | 0     | EXP1 | TRUE    |
55 | 30    | EXP2 | TRUE    |
70 | 30    | EXP3 | FALSE   |
99 | 42    | EXP4 | FALSE   |
232| 0     | EXP5 | TRUE    |
65 | 232   | EXP6 | TRUE    |
-----------------------------
```

Expected result:

```
----------------------------
ID | SUBID | NAME | ENABLED |
30 | 0     | EXP1 | TRUE    |
55 | 30    | EXP2 | TRUE    |
70 | 30    | EXP3 | FALSE   |
232| 0     | EXP5 | TRUE    |
65 | 232   | EXP6 | TRUE    |
-----------------------------
```

If someone could help me how to write this `SQL statement` in a good way I will be grateful.

Comment: There are a number of answers that all seem to interpret your question differently.  I think you need to try to explain your requirements more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Exists':

```
SELECT T1.* FROM TEST T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT T2.ID FROM TEST T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.SUBID)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT T3.SUBID FROM TEST T3 WHERE T3.SUBID = T1.ID)
```

Test Result:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=adfa22556a421cb291c6fde2d6cae561)

Answer (score 0):

How about a union

```
select a.*
from have a
inner join have b
    on a.subid=b.id
union
select b.*
from have a
inner join have b
    on a.subid=b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be actually pretty complicated, as you've evidently found out. I'd suggest a CTE and a UNION with your JOINs and aliases. It also looks like it'll need all that in a subquery to do a DISTINCT, too.

Without testing this, I'd image it looks something like this:

```
WITH MAIN AS (  
SELECT ID, SUBID, NAME  
FROM TABLE t  
WHERE ENABLED = TRUE  
)

SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME  
FROM (
    SELECT ID, NAME  
    FROM MAIN
    UNION
    SELECT t.ID, t.NAME 
    FROM MAIN
    LEFT JOIN TABLE t on MAIN.SUBID = t.ID
    WHERE MAIN.SUBID <> 0
)
```

The outer select might not be needed if you do a distinct on each of the inner queries, but without testing it, I can't say for sure. I'd guess it would only DISTINCT the two lists separately, which isn't your intended result.

I'm kind of hoping someone else can come up with a less complicated version.  I'd also suggest you do some more research on CTEs, UNIONs, aliases, and see if you can make this simpler on your own.  But this should get you in the right direction.

BTW, I used a CTE (WITH MAIN AS) so that the query wouldn't be duplicated.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that justifies `WHERE ENABLED = TRUE`

Comment: That was an assumption on my part.  I also assumed the OP could take it out if they didn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script-

```
SELECT YT.* 
FROM your_table YT
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(B.ID)
    FROM your_table A
    LEFT JOIN your_table B 
        ON A.SUBID = B.ID
    WHERE B.ID IS NOT NULL
) C ON YT.ID = C.ID OR YT.SUBID = C.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding of what you are trying to do, you simply want:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t1
  WHERE SubID = 0
     OR EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM myTable t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.SubID)
```